An exercise about pushforward measures and density measures. Carathéodory's extension theorem
Let the function $\varphi:(0, + \infty) \to (0, + \infty)$ be defined by $\varphi(x) = 2x$ and $\mathcal{B}$ the Borel sigma algebra in $(0, + \infty)$. Let $\mu$ be a measure defined in $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mu \circ \varphi^{-1}$ the pushforward measure  of $\mu$ with respect to $\varphi$.
a) If $\mu$ is such that $\mu = \mu \circ \varphi^{-1}$, prove that for all $x >0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\mu ((x, + \infty)) = \mu ((2^nx, + \infty)) = \mu(( \frac{x}{2^n}, + \infty)).$
b) Is there any probability measure $\mu$ defined in $\mathcal{B}$ such that $\mu = \mu \circ \varphi^{-1}$?
c) Let $\nu$ be the measure in $\mathcal{B}$ with density $\frac{1}{t}$ with respect to Lebesgue measure in $\mathcal{B}$. Prove that $\nu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure such that $\nu = \nu \circ \varphi^{-1}$.
My attempt
a) We proceed by induction.
Let us show that $\mu ((x, + \infty)) =  \mu (( \frac{x}{2^n}, + \infty))$ for all $x >0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ .
$n=1:$ $$\mu ((\frac{x}{2}, + \infty)) = \mu (\varphi^{-1} (x, + \infty)) = \mu \circ \varphi^{-1} ((x, + \infty)) = \mu ((x, + \infty)) .$$
$n \Rightarrow n+1:$
$$\mu ((\frac{x}{2^{n+1}}, + \infty))  =  \mu (\varphi^{-1} (\frac{x}{2^{n}}, + \infty)) = \mu \circ \varphi^{-1} ((\frac{x}{2^{n}}, + \infty)) =  \mu ((\frac{x}{2^{n}}, + \infty)) = / \text{induction step}/  = \mu ((x + \infty)). $$
Let us show similarly that $\mu ((x, + \infty)) = \mu ((2^nx, + \infty))$ for all $x >0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}.$
$n=1 :$ $$\mu ((2x, + \infty)) = \mu \circ \varphi^{-1} ((2x, + \infty)) = \mu (\varphi^{-1} (2x, + \infty)) = \mu ((x, + \infty)).$$
$n \Rightarrow n+1:$
$$\mu ((2^{n+1}x, + \infty))  =  \mu \circ \varphi^{-1} (( 2^{n+1}x, + \infty)) = \mu (\varphi^{-1} (2^{n+1}x, + \infty))  =  \mu ((2^{n}x, + \infty)) = / \text{induction step}/ = \mu ((x + \infty)). $$
b) By contradiction, let us suppose that there is such probability measure $\mu$ such that $\mu = \mu \circ \varphi^{-1}$. Then it must verify $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$, $\mu((0, + \infty)) = 1$ and countable additivity. Therefore, we have for $x > 0$:
$1 = \mu ((0, + \infty)) = \mu ( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} ( \frac{x}{2^n}, + \infty)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu ( \frac{x}{2^n}, + \infty) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu (( x, + \infty)) = \mu (( x, + \infty)),$
so $$1 = \mu (( x, + \infty)).$$
However:
$0 = \mu (\emptyset) = \mu ( \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} ( 2^nx, + \infty)) = //   \mu ((2^nx, + \infty)) = \mu ((x, + \infty)) =1 < \infty// = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu ((2^n x, + \infty)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu (( x, + \infty)) =  \mu (( x, + \infty)) =1 !!$
c) To prove that $\nu = \nu \circ \varphi^{-1}$, it suffices to see that both measures are the same for the elements of
$$I = \ \{ (a, b] \subset (0 , + \infty ): a < b, a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}. $$
Let $0 < a < b$, then
$$\nu ((a, b]) = \int_{(a,b]} \frac{1}{t} dm = \log t |_{a}^{b} = \log \frac{b}{a}.$$
Also:
$$\nu \circ \varphi^{-1} ((a, b]) = \nu ((\frac{a}{2}, \frac{b}{2}]) = \int_{(\frac{a}{2},\frac{b}{2}]} \frac{1}{t} dm =  \log \frac{b}{a}.$$
Besides, $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite:
$$(0, +\infty ) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} ( \frac{1}{n}, n],$$
where these intervals have finite measure.
Is my attempt correct? Any suggestions or corrections are welcome. Thanks.

What's the question?

Is my attempt correct?

Yes, it is correct.
